# How do I reload a view from the storyboard (or otherwise manage low memory condition)?

Tags: ios

In developing my current app, I ran into some issues that I eventually traced back to a low memory warning.  Part of the low memory is coming from my (liberal) use of UIWebViews, which are apparently consuming a lot of memory.

I didn't think this would be an issue, since a view that isn't currently visible should just vanish when the low memory warning is thrown, unfortunately it turns out that anything connected to the UITabBarController remains in the heirarchy and doesn't release.  By manually releasing (and then recreating in viewWillAppear) the views, I make things work decently.  But it doesn't completely solve the memory warning issue.

So what I need to do is manually release the view -- and the large amount of memory that winds up connected to it -- and then restore it.  Since I don't want to build it programmatically (that's what IB is for!), I need to somehow reload it from storyboard.

Or, alternatively, I'm being an idiot and there's something really obvious to make my life easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more experimentation, it turns out that on the one hand, my understanding of view life cycles was slightly flawed, and on the other my experiments were tainted by having accidentally let zombie objects on.

Views will, in fact, unload their contents in a low memory condition and reload them later -- that's part of what 'viewDidLoad' and 'viewDidUnload' are designed for!  Putting init code in them, as some tutorials I read did, was a major error.  That init code should go in the designated initializer -- even if that can be annoying to figure out which initializer is designated.

Comment: Putting initialization code in `-viewDidLoad` is not that bad if you don't need the data before the view is loaded; you just need to be aware that it can be called twice. Also note that `-viewDidUnload` is now deprecated and views are not automatically unloaded on memory warnings anymore because too many apps were breaking on memory warnings (ironic given that in iOS 4 or 5 they changed it so memory warnings forcibly unloaded views even if you overrode `-didReceiveMemoryWarning`).

Comment: So then how to do it?  I've similar issue: app keeps getting kicked on men warning... The story board is empty view into which I then draw wkWebKit on ViewDidLoad... which (browsing around) than apparently bloats the app up where it gets kicked once on background....  Can I dump the whole thing in memwarning, and how would I then tell it to reload the nib in the willenterforeground so it goes through the motions of viewDidLoad so I can rebuild the wkwebview (and possibly renavigate to url that was last at at the time of low men call) Thank you

Comment: @danchik if you have only the one view, and that view by itself is triggering memory warnings, what you need to do is find out why you're using that much memory and fix it.

Comment: There is nothing in the view but wkWebKit - New project / ios / single view.... and then draw wkWebKit into it (in ViewDidLoad) and constrain align it to the guidelines that were already in the view and navigate to a URL... and this causes mem warning when in background (if you spent any significant time on that web page before the app went to background)... Yes the web page is bloated, but that is not a source I have control over, for all I know